# CSV Reader para agrupar filas y concatenar en python

Tags: python, funciones, csv

Tengo un archivo de texto que tiene un formato definido en cuanto a campos (pero con cantidad de caracteres aleatorios y datos que debo concatenar a algunos campos de las filas anteriores.
El contenido del archivo sería:

```
"Socio 34","01/10/2021","19/10/2021","1005","V","   3                          ", 
"Sucursal 2","OTERO MARIA                        ","Cordova 97                ","CF                       "," 80","F", 
"*","4222836        ","31/10/1943","*                             ","2","*      ", 
"G   "
"Socio 34", 
 3 
" 1       Libro56L 4"
" 2      Ensayo297E 3"
" 3      Libro475L 2"
"Socio 5","01/10/2021","13/10/2021","1005","N"," 164                          ", 
"Sucursal 1","CURETTA JOSE                          ","Madrid 7412                 ","PBA                       "," 170","M",
"*","9332999       ","20/10/1950","*                             ","2","*      ", 
"G   "
"Socio 5", 
 1 
" 1       Enciclopedia95E 9"
"Socio 144","01/10/2021","20/10/2021","1005","N","1000                          ", 
"Sucursal 2","FERNANDEZ Fernanda                 ","Valencia 6984                 ","CBA                       "," 64","F",
"*","1296761        ","01/03/1957","*                             ","2","*      ", 
"G   "
"Socio 144",
 4 
" 1     Ensayo1712E 1"
" 2     Revista192R 1"
" 3     Revista157R 4"
" 4     Cuaderno478C 2"
```

Lo que quiero hacer es juntar las primeras 3 líneas para cada socio y de ahi extraer lo campos que hacen falta, en este caso:
`{socio};{nombre};{fecha_prestamo};{fecha_devolucion};{fnac};{sexo}` que en el primer caso serían:
`Socio 34, Otero Maria, 01/10/2021; 19/10/2021, 31/10/1943, F`. Este paso lo tengo resuelto con csv.reader, pero no encuentro la forma para obtener el siguiente resultado final. Cada socio tiene x cantidad de libros en préstamo (fila 6). Esa fila me dice cuantas veces tengo que mostrar los datos de los socios con los libros en préstamo, que seria lo siguiente para el caso 1:

`Socio 34, Otero Maria, 01/10/2021; 19/10/2021, 31/10/1943, F, 56

Socio 34, Otero Maria, 01/10/2021; 19/10/2021, 31/10/1943, F, 297

Socio 34, Otero Maria, 01/10/2021; 19/10/2021, 31/10/1943, F, 475`

Y así para cada uno de los socios.

La primera parte que tengo hasta ahora es:

```
import csv
with open("E:\BibliotecaZonal-102021.txt") as csvfile:
    csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    data = []
    sublist = []
    i = 1
    for row in csvdata:
        #print(', '.join(row))
        if (len(row) > 1):
            if (i%4 != 0):
                sublist.extend(row)
            else:
                data.append(sublist)
                sublist = []
            i += 1
for row in data:
    fecha_prestamo = row[1].strip()
    fecha_devolucion = row[2].strip()
    socio = row[0].strip()
    nombre = row[8].strip()
    sexo = row[12].strip()
    fnac = row[16].strip()
    print(f'{socio};{nombre};{fecha_prestamo};{fecha_devolucion};{fnac};{sexo}')
```

Estuve trabajando con una funcion que primero me tome estos datos y luego me agregue loss libros, pero no me funciono y la verdad es que estoy en un loop de ideas que no funcionan.

Cualquier idea se agradece.

Answer (score 2):

Esta un poco extraño de parsear ese archivo, pero con los registros que mostraste pude construir uno que al menos sirva para ellos.

La variable `i` es el contador de líneas de todos los datos para cada socio. O sea, cuando llega a un socio nuevo se resetea a 0. Y, debido a que estamos usando listas, se necesita conocer el índice numérico del socio actual, por eso la variable idx_socio.

```
import csv

data = []
with open("E:\\BibliotecaZonal-102021.txt") as csvfile:
    csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    idx_socio = -1
    i = 0
    for row in csvdata:
        if row[0].startswith('Socio') and i != 4:
            data.append({})
            idx_socio += 1
            data[idx_socio]['socio'] = row[0]
            data[idx_socio]['prestamo'] = row[1]
            data[idx_socio]['devolucion'] = row[2]
            i = 0
        elif i == 1:
            data[idx_socio]['nombre'] = row[1].strip()
            data[idx_socio]['sexo'] = row[5]
        elif i == 2:
            data[idx_socio]['fnac'] = row[2]
            data[idx_socio]['libros'] = []
        elif i >= 6:
            data[idx_socio]['libros'].append(row[0])
        else:
            pass
        i += 1
print(data)
```

Al final de la ejecución de este código, `data` tendrá el siguiente contenido:

```
[
    {
        'socio': 'Socio 34', 
        'prestamo': '01/10/2021', 
        'devolucion': '19/10/2021', 
        'nombre': 'OTERO MARIA', 
        'sexo': 'F', 
        'fnac': '31/10/1943', 
        'libros': [
            ' 1       Libro56L 4', 
            ' 2      Ensayo297E 3', 
            ' 3      Libro475L 2'
        ]
    },
    { Socio 2 ... }, 
    { Socio 3 ... }, 
    { ... etc ... }
]
```

Otra forma de mostrarlo es haciendo que el **socio** sea índice de cada item del arreglo. Haciendo un par de modificaciones quedaría la siguiente forma:

```
import csv

data = {}
with open("E:\\BibliotecaZonal-102021.txt") as csvfile:
    csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    idx_socio = None
    i = 0
    for row in csvdata:
        if row[0].startswith('Socio') and i != 4:
            idx_socio = row[0]
            data[idx_socio] = {}
            data[idx_socio]['prestamo'] = row[1]
            data[idx_socio]['devolucion'] = row[2]
            i = 0
        elif i == 1:
            data[idx_socio]['nombre'] = row[1].strip()
            data[idx_socio]['sexo'] = row[5]
        elif i == 2:
            data[idx_socio]['fnac'] = row[2]
            data[idx_socio]['libros'] = []
        elif i >= 6:
            data[idx_socio]['libros'].append(row[0])
        else:
            pass
        i += 1
                    
print(data)
```

Con esta versión `data` dará una salida así:

```
{
    'Socio 34': {
        'prestamo': '01/10/2021', 
        'devolucion': '19/10/2021', 
        'nombre': 'OTERO MARIA', 
        'sexo': 'F', 
        'fnac': '31/10/1943', 
        'libros': [
            ' 1       Libro56L 4', 
            ' 2      Ensayo297E 3', 
            ' 3      Libro475L 2'
        ]
    }, 
    'Socio 5': { 
        ... 
    }
    ... etc
}
```

Cualquiera de las 2 formas sirven para ser utilizados en una aplicación o ser convertidos directamente a JSON y ser servidos por el sistema.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la respuesta, me sirve para poder tener los datos importantes juntos. Aunque todavia no pude llegar a ver como concatenar los datos para entregar
Socio 34, Otero Maria, 01/10/2021; 19/10/2021, 31/10/1943, F, 56 /n
Socio 34, Otero Maria, 01/10/2021; 19/10/2021, 31/10/1943, F, 297 /n
Socio 34, Otero Maria, 01/10/2021; 19/10/2021, 31/10/1943, F, 475 /n

sigo intentando, gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Con lo anterior ya tienes toda la data en un arreglo, eso es lo más importante y era la parte más complicada @LuisDesdeCanada . Ahora es solo cuestión de ir recorriendolo y pedirle los datos que desees, por ejemplo, usando el segundo caso, puedes escribir `for key,value in data.items():` y luego en la siguente línea (indentada) `print(f'{key};{value["nombre"]};{value["prestamo"]};{value["devolucion"]};etc')`

Comment: Solo falta separar los números del tipo de libro en `" 2     Revista192R 1"`
```for dato in lista:
    for libro in dato['libros']:
        num = re.findall('[0-9]+', libro.split()[1])[0]
        print(f'{dato["Socio"]}, {dato["Nombre"]}, {dato["Prestamo"]}, {dato["Devolucion"]}, {dato["f_nac"]}, {dato["Sexo"]}, {num}')```

Comment: Gracias Tomy y @aeportugal por la paciencia para enseñarme, debo reconocer que viviendo de otro campo y con la edad me cuesta bastante. Gracias por compartir sus conocimientos. Esta noche lo probare con la extensa lista que tengo

Answer (score 1):

Una vez que tienes el código de @aeportugal (el primer código, el que genera una lista de diccionarios) solo queda recorrer la lista.

Como harán falta expresiones regulares hay que importar el módulo

```
import re
```

En el diccionario `{libros}` se guarda el dato completo `' 1       Libro56L 4'` y quieres solo `56`.

`libro.split()[1]` para crear una lista y separar los tres valores y quedarnos con el segundo `Libro56L` .

Ahora falta separar los números con `re.findall()`

`num = re.findall('[0-9]+', libro.split()[1])[0]`

[Ejemplos de expresiones regulares](https://pythonconejemplos.xyz/python/extraer-o-encontrar-todos-los-numeros-de-una-cadena-regex-python/)

```
for dato in data:
    for libro in dato['libros']:
        num = re.findall('[0-9]+', libro.split()[1])[0]
        print(f'{dato["Socio"]}, {dato["Nombre"]}, {dato["Prestamo"]}, {dato["Devolucion"]}, {dato["f_nac"]}, {dato["Sexo"]}, {num}')
```

Igual lo que quieres es modificar el código de @aeportugal y crear las salidas directamente.

```
import csv
import re

import pprint

nom_fich = 'biblioteca.txt'
with open(nom_fich) as csvfile:
    csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    i = 0

    for linea in csvdata:
        if linea[0].startswith('Socio') and i != 4:
            #   pprint.pprint(linea)
            i = 0
            socio = linea[0]
            fecha_prestamo = linea[1]
            fecha_devolucion = linea[2]

        elif i == 1:
            #   pprint.pprint(linea)
            nombre = linea[1].strip().title()
            sexo = linea[5]

        elif i == 2:
            pprint.pprint(linea)
            fnac = linea[2]

        elif i >= 6:
            #   pprint.pprint(linea)
            libro = linea[0].split()[1]
            num = re.findall('[0-9]+', libro)[0]
            print(f'{socio}, {nombre}, {fecha_prestamo}, {fecha_devolucion}, {fnac}, {sexo}, {num}')

        else:
            pass

        i += 1
```

Se van guardando los datos de cada tarjeta en variables, se imprimen y se pierden.

**Editado:**

`linea` es una lista y para cada linea del fichero tendrá valores diferentes.

Imagino que en tu fichero original en la tercera linea (`i == 2`) tiene menos de tres datos.

Para que visualices los datos de esa lista verticalmente te añado `pprint(linea)`, para que te sea más sencillo encontrar los datos que buscas.

Comment: Hola Tomy, muchas gracias por la ayuda, funciono muy bien con el ejemplo de prueba, cuando intente correrlo con el archivo original me tira un error en ```elif i == 2:``` que dice ```list index out of range```, parece que no saltara de linea. Estuve tratando de encontrar diferencia entre el ejemplo y el original y es que las lineas ahora tienen mas campos. el ``` 1!= 4 ``` como juega aqui?

Comment: Cuando lee la **primera linea** `i == 0` y cuando lees la **quinta linea** `i == 4`. En ambos casos la linea empieza por  **Socio**, pero solo importan los resultados de la primera. Para  ayudarte a buscar el dato en cada linea puedes usar `pprint`. Edito la respuesta para que veas de donde sale cada dato.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Estoy medio abrumado, tenia una forma de hacerlo antes que me funcionaba muy bien y me cambiaron un campo (que antes la cantidad de caracteres era fija y ahora es variable) y me mataron... y uno lo hace para colaborar de buena onda y se trabo todo... Gracias

Comment: Gracias Tomy, ya funciona, lo que pasabaen las cientos de lineas, que aparecia un Socio con la linea 2 (en vez de ser siempre Sucursal) y eso trababa todo...
Mil gracias por la ayuda!!